# All the solutions of linear Diophantine equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Given the linear Diophantine equation:

$ a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + ... + a_n x_n = b$

and its particular solution $(x_1^*, x_2^*, ..., x_n^*)$.

How to write down all the solutions of this equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, complete the vector $(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$ to a matrix $A$ with determinant $1.$ Then the solutions (of the homogeneous system) are all integer linear combinations of the second through $n$ *columns* of $A^{-1}.$ That you can complete the vector with gcd 1 to a unimodular matrix is basic to geometry of numbers, and can be proved fairly easily by induction (or see Morris Newman's book on "Integral Matrices", Thm II.1).

Comment: OK, but i wonder if there exists the way to find inverse of unimodular matrix without using rationals (without divisions) in O(P(n)) where P is some polynom?

Comment: @ИльяМурадьян There is a difference between not using divisions and not using rationals. In the proof of the result I quote you divide a set of numbers by their gcd (which leads to no rationals). I don't think you can avoid divisions, but you can certainly do all the necessary computations with integers.

Comment: ok, I've built an example. Let a = (3, 5, 7). Then A = (3 5 7 | 1 2 0 | -3 -5 -6) and A^(-1) = (-12 -5 -14 | 6 3 7 | 1 0 1). You say that x = k(6 3 7) + l(1 0 1) should be solution of an equation 3x1 + 5x2 + 7x3 = 0 for any integer k and l, but it isn't so. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @ИльяМурадьян My typo - by "rows" I meant "columns". Fixed now.